# The arxiv API as described in the documentation does not seem to work. Any explanations?

Tags: arxiv

The docs here:

https://info.arxiv.org/help/api/basics.html#quickstart

say:

> API calls are made via an HTTP GET or POST requests to an appropriate
> url. For example, the url
>
> http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=all:electron
>
> retrieves results that match the search query all:electron

However, all I get back is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <link href="http://arxiv.org/api/query?search_query%3Dall%3Aelectron%26id_list%3D%26start%3D0%26max_results%3D10" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"/>
  <title type="html">ArXiv Query: search_query=all:electron&amp;id_list=&amp;start=0&amp;max_results=10</title>
  <id>http://arxiv.org/api/WyBPOs+pRgzCTXTMWhtnbcOmk6g</id>
  <updated>2023-10-17T00:00:00-04:00</updated>
  <opensearch:totalResults xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">0</opensearch:totalResults>
  <opensearch:startIndex xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">0</opensearch:startIndex>
  <opensearch:itemsPerPage xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">10</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
</feed>
```

Am I misunderstanding what it means by `retrieves results that match the search query all:electron`?